# IE version 9 and below not switching thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Clicking each thumbnail on the side of the product page will switch the big_image to show that image as normal. Works fine on anything other than Internet Explorer 9 or lower. Don't see any immediate reason why though. I am testing by using the Dev tools of internet explorer to emulate v9 and below as I don't have them installed. Some people have previously said that they have no issue though but I and second & third computer with IE definitely has too.

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1bEfjYf

```
<?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
<div class="left">
  <div class="image-additional">
    <a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img class="side_thumb" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a>

    <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img class="side_thumb"  src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="big_image">
    <img width="320" height="320" name="main" src="<?php echo $popup; ?>" alt="">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.side_thumb').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).parent('a').attr('href'));
    $("#big_image").html($('<img width="320" height="320">').attr("src", $(e.currentTarget).parent('a').attr('href')));
    //$("#big_image").prop('src',$(e.currentTarget).attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Does it show the image in the browser?

Comment: I click the thumbnail and it simply does nothing, it should as normal just switch the large image with the one you've selected from the thumbnails.

Comment: it works in IE8 when I enable Debugging. Otherwise I get a `console is undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some versions of IE, the `console` object isn't present until Developer Tools are opened, which can often cause Heisenbugs where things don't work, then you open Dev Tools to see why and they start working.

Testing your site on IE8, this seems to be the case, and I do get a "`console` is undefined" error in the lower left corner, so try removing your call to `console.log`.

Comment: Never come across this before but yep works great now, thank you!

Comment: @JordanC26 Anytime! I know how you feel - I only came across this a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Just   use `this` to target the image in the handler

```
$('.side_thumb').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent('a').attr('href'));
    $("#big_image").html('<img width="320" height="320" src="'+$(this).parent('a').attr('href')+'">');
})
```

Comment: Switched to this (still live) and just the same, no change when using v9 and below. Click the thumbnail and nothing.

Comment: Seems to have been simply a matter of removing the console.log call to fix this but I appreciate the code fix too!